# what is the best mysql database model for users with permissions

Tags: mysql

i have a table of users where each user should have a list of permissions.
i have red in another answer that i should use a second table called permissions with a user id to assign the permission to a specific user.

```
userID  | permission   
--------|----------
     1  | read
     1  | write
     1  | delete
```

with this solution i can just select all permissions with the id of the user and get all the permissions of a specific user.

what i think to be inefficient about this is the fact that all permissions will repeat for different users in this table.

```
userID  | permission   
--------|----------
     1  | read
     1  | write
     1  | delete
     2  | write <- repeating with different userid
```

in my case i will have at least 150 users and probably more than 100 permissions
which will make the table kind of big ?

i would guess this is a very common case to have. but i could not find a better way.

Comment: 100x150=15k, which is by no means big. Even if your permission field is on average 10 byte long per record vs 1 byte / tinyint with a normalised model, we talk about 135KB difference in size.  It is not really the size of the tables that drives normalization.

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a new table with the list of all possible permissions and link those ID's with the User ID's.

```
- Permissions      ( ID     | Description  )
- User Permissions ( UserId | PermissionID )
```

To select all the permissions for a single User

```
    SELECT Permissions.* 
    FROM UserPermissions 
    LEFT JOIN Permissions ON Permissions.id = UserPermissions.PermissionId
    WHERE UserPermissions.UserID = {userId}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do not make third table like this?

```
userID  | other columns for users
--------|-------------------------
     1  | 
     2  | 
     3  | 

userID  | permissionID   
--------|----------
     1  | 1
     1  | 2
     1  | 3
     2  | 2

permissionID  | permissionName   
--------------|----------
           1  | read
           2  | write
           3  | delete
```